# $http request giving 403 after using Spring Security?

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-security, http-headers, http-post

Below is my SecurityConfiguration class, I am using.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class WebMvcConfig {
@Configuration
protected static class SecurityConfiguration extends 
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


  http.authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
  .anyRequest().authenticated()
  .and()
  .formLogin().permitAll();
  }
}
```

After startup, as soon as I hit my URL (http://localhost:8080/TestApp/), it takes me to the default login page and when I enter the default user Id (user) and password (printed on the console), it take me to my index.html page mapped by the "/" URL via my AngularJS routing. I am able to navigate through the UI but as soon as I submit any $http request (I am trying with a POST request), it gives me 403 on the browser console with my $http request URL.

Can someone help?

Comment: try adding `http.csrf().disable();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Error 403** means that you are forbidden from accessing all the resources.

If you inspect the error details, more probably you will have a message such as `Expected CSRF token not found`.

From v4 onwards, `spring security` enables by default `csrf` protection. This is a good practice as `csrf` attacks force an end user to execute unwanted actions on a web application in which they’re currently authenticated.

So in a dev environment, adding `http.csrf().disable();` will solve your problem. But you should consider adding a `csrf` token when you want to move to a prod env.